# Find Combination of String

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a string format as '2112';
The possible combination should represent an Alphabet.

2,112 is not allowed as 112 is a three digit character and it cannot represent an alphabet, so basically 'a' represents 1 and 'z' represents 26.

like for this the possible combination is (2,1,1,2), (21,1,2),(2,11,2),(2,1,12),(21,21).

So here the characters are not reordered but have been split into combinations.
How do I approach it?

My tries:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(permutationFinder("2112"));
}

private static Set<String> permutationFinder(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

    }



    Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
    if(str == null){
        return null;
    }
    else if(str.length()==0){
        stringSet.add("");
        return stringSet;
    }
    char initial = str.charAt(0);
    String rem = str.substring(1);
    Set<String> words = permutationFinder(rem);

    for(String word : words){
        int length = word.length();
        for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++){
            stringSet.add(merge(word, initial, i));
        }
    }

    return stringSet;
}

private static String merge(String word, char initial, int i) {
    String begin = word.substring(0,i);
    String end = word.substring(i);
    return begin + initial + end;
}
```

But this gives combination.

Comment: What have you tried? Why is (2,112) and (211,2) not allowed?

Comment: 2,112 is not allowed as 112 is a three digit character and it cannot represent an alphabet, so basically 'a' represents 1 and 'z' represents 26.

Comment: So you want to find all the different ways a given String can be partitioned into 1- and 2-character substrings.  Is that basically the task?

Comment: Are you supposed to list all of them, or just count them? Counting them can be done way more efficiently.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you're supposed to split it such that each element is between 1 and 26?

Comment: Yeah count them, Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn’t understand how your method was supposed to work, and then of course neither why it didn’t, sorry.

The standard solution for a combination problem like this one is recursion, the concept of a method calling it self to have a part of its task done. If you don’t know recursion, look it up and prepare for a learning curve. In this case I suggest that the method finds the possible first letters in the beginning of the string (in your example they would be 2 and 21), then calls itself recursively to find all possible combinations of the remainder of the string, finally puts the pieces together to form a full solution. Since we always call with ever shorter string arguments, we can be sure that the recursion will not continue infinitely. Sooner or later we will pass the empty string. So the first thing to consider is, what is the desired result for an empty string? It’s the empty list of letters. Now we can write the method:

```
private static List<List<String>> combinationFinder(String str) {
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.singletonList(Collections.emptyList());
    }
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // can we split off 1 char from the start? requires just non-zero
    if (str.charAt(0) != '0') {
        String firstChar = str.substring(0, 1);
        if (!Character.isDigit(firstChar.charAt(0))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a digit: " + firstChar);
        }
        List<List<String>> combinationsOfRemainingStr 
                = combinationFinder(str.substring(1));
        addAllCombos(result, firstChar, combinationsOfRemainingStr);
    }
    // can we split off 2 chars?
    if (str.length() >= 2) {
        String firstSubstring = str.substring(0, 2);
        int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(firstSubstring);
        if (firstNumber >= 1 && firstNumber <= 26) { // OK
            List<List<String>> combinationsOfRemainingStr 
                    = combinationFinder(str.substring(2));
            addAllCombos(result, firstSubstring, combinationsOfRemainingStr);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/** adds to result all lists made up of firstElement followed by a list from remainingElements */
private static void addAllCombos(List<List<String>> result,
        String firstElement, List<List<String>> remainingElements) {
    for (List<String> remCombo : remainingElements) {
        List<String> totalCombo = new ArrayList<>(1 + remCombo.size());
        totalCombo.add(firstElement);
        totalCombo.addAll(remCombo);
        result.add(totalCombo);
    }
}
```

With your input example, `2112`, this returns:

```
[[2, 1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 12], [2, 11, 2], [21, 1, 2], [21, 12]]
```

I believe this is exactly what you asked for.

The method is a little bit inconsistent as I wrote it: it will find 01 as a letter from the beginning of the string, but neither 001 nor 026. If this is an issue, I trust you to mend it.

Comment: considering input as 2102; it would return 02 in 2 out of 3 subsets [[2, 1, 02], [2, 10, 2], [21, 02]] which will be invalid. So, after returning, i looped though the values and removed the sets which have any value starting 0;  
Apart from this; can u suggest me any other optimum solution to not include the invalid sets?

Comment: @srp321, I don’t think it’s difficult. I understand that a character value cannot begin with 0. So if in a call the string passed begins with 0, nothing should be returned. If you put all of the last `if` statement, ` if (str.length() >= 2)` …, inside the first `if` statement, right after `addAllCombos(result, firstChar, combinationsOfRemainingStr);`, then I think you’re done. Then it will only be executed of the first char of the string is not `0`.

Comment: Then you should also not redeclare `combinationsOfRemainingStr` since the previously declared variable by this name is still in scope. Just reuse it.

Comment: that did work; thanks, my other way was longer; this made it quite short.
  Yes, we don't need to redeclare that one also

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to

```
private static Set<String> findCharacterEquivalants(String str){
    Set<String> charEqs = new HashSet<>();
    int strLen = str.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < strLen; i++){
        if(str.charAt(i) == '0'){
            //Skip it since 0 is not a match for any character
            continue;
        }

        //single character which is not zero is always a match
        charEqs.add("" + str.charAt(i));

        switch(str.charAt(i)){
            case '1' : 
                //Check to see whether combination of this char with the next char is a match
                if((i + 1) < strLen){
                    charEqs.add("" + str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i + 1));
                }
                break;
            case '2' :
                 //Check to see whether combination of this char with the next char is a match.
                if(((i + 1) < strLen)
                          && (str.charAt(i + 1) == '0' || str.charAt(i + 1) == '1' || str.charAt(i + 1) == '2' || str.charAt(i + 1) == '3' || str.charAt(i + 1) == '4' || str.charAt(i + 1) == '5' || str.charAt(i + 1) == '6')){
                    charEqs.add("" + str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i + 1));
                }
        }
    }

    return charEqs;

}
```

Note that this method takes the assumption that the permutations keep the order of characters in the string supplied. If you want to allow duplication of these substrings, use a List instead of Set.

Comment: This does not give the required output of `(2,1,1,2),(21,1,2),(2,11,2),(2,1,12),(21,12)` for `"2112"`.